# Centralized Logging of methods: framework to implement it

Tags: c#, google-analytics, usage-statistics

I suspect that one of the c# method is never called (because of if codintions); but the software is a client and it's distributed to 1000 users. 
So I would like to call some remote API to log every time the method is accessed.

This kind of tracking has got a name? Is it possible to use Google Analytics through c# as a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy to achieve using Google Analytics.

[Is there any way to post events to Google Analytics via server-side API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9503329/is-there-any-way-to-post-events-to-google-analytics-via-server-side-api)

A c# wrapper has already been provided:

https://gist.github.com/0liver/11229128